# This Developer Name is invalid Error in salesforce 1 Error

Tags: salesforce1-app, reporting

[image]

We are showing a Report chart on Record detail page, it is working fine on browser(Desktop) but when we try to open this detail page on Salesforce 1 that time it's showing above error.

```
This developer name is invalid. Provide the developer name for the report that contain the chart.
```

We have created a report as a chart and showing on record detail page of a custom object.

The name of report is "My 30-Day Mood Meter 2".